# Django, URL and Views not found

Tags: django, django-views, url-pattern

I'm using Django 2.1 and testing views.py and urls.py
What I don't understand is why whenever I enter the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/post_list I get a 404 error message

My top urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from organizer import urls as organizer_urls
from blog import urls as blog_urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(organizer_urls)),
    path('tag/', include(organizer_urls)),
    path('startup/', include(organizer_urls)),
    path('blog/', include(blog_urls))
]
```

my application's urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from blog.views import post_list, post_detail

urlpatterns = [
    path('',
        post_list,
        name='blog_post_list'),
    path(
        '<int:year>/<int:month>/<slug:slug>',
        post_detail,
        name='blog_post_detail'),
]
```

my application's views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post
# Create your views here.

def post_list(request):
    return render(
        request,
        'blog/post_list.html',
        {'post_list':Post.object.all()}
    )

def post_detail(request, year, month, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(
        Post,
        pub_date__year=year,
        pub_date__month=month,
        slug=slug)
    return render(
        request,
        'blog/post_detail.html',
        {'post': post})
```

the error message is:

> Using the URLconf defined in suorganizer_project.urls, Django tried
>   these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> admin/ tag/tag_list [name='organizer_tag_list'] tag//
>   startup/startup_list [name='organizer_startup_list'] startup//
>   [name='organizer_startup_detail'] tag/ startup/ blog/ The empty path
>   didn't match any of these.

Why ? The url is  there:

```
path('',
        post_list,
        name='blog_post_list'),
```

which would take me to post_list views:

```
def post_list(request):
    return render(
        request,
        'blog/post_list.html',
        {'post_list':Post.object.all()}
    )
```

and returns a query for all objects in post --Post.object.all()-- ?

I don't understand what i'm missing, would appreciate your help ! :)

Comment: `path('', post_list, name='blog_post_list'),` change this line to `path('post_list/', post_list, name='blog_post_list'),`

Comment: I'm still new to stackoverflow, but how can I upvote your comment ? :)
Thanks

Comment: you don't have enough reputations to up-vote comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post_list` is not in your URL pattern, but it is your function name. If you access the URL that way: `127.0.0.1:8000/blog/` it will work and call `post_list()` view based on this pattern

```
path('',
    post_list,
    name='blog_post_list'),
```

If you want to have your URL works, just edit your pattern the following way by adding the `post_list` string.

```
path('post_list',
    post_list,
    name='blog_post_list'),
```

Comment: Many thanks @Lemayzeur, I missed that fact that my '' in the urlpatterns comes after /blog

Thanks for the clarification
Cheers